# installing transmission on debian with docker: Missing container

Tags: docker

I am new to this. I have installed docker on my Raspi. I am trying to install transmission on the docker. I use the following;

```bash
docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN -d \
          --name=transmission \
          -v /mnt/extDrive1:/data \
          -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro \
          -e CREATE_TUN_DEVICE=true \
          -e OPENVPN_PROVIDER=EXPRESSVPN \
          -e OPENVPN_CONFIG=my_expressvpn_uk_-_london_udp \
          -e OPENVPN_USERNAME=XXX\
          -e OPENVPN_PASSWORD=XXX \
          -e WEBPROXY_ENABLED=false \
          -e LOCAL_NETWORK=192.168.0.0 \
          --log-driver json-file \
          --log-opt max-size=10m \
          -p 9091:9091 \
          haugene/transmission-openvpn
```

I go through the debug on https://haugene.github.io/docker-transmission-openvpn/debug/

All is fine until I get to the section 'Checking if Transmission is running'.

When I run `docker ps`, there are no containers in the list.

What have I done wrong? Ultimately, I am trying to access transmission through `localhost:9091`.

Edit: So I have made some progress, but still having issues;

`docker start transmission` temporarily. populates the container ID

`docker exec -it <container-id> bash` comes up with the following error:

> Error response from daemon: Container XXXX is not running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that container is exiting out as you are not running it in the detached mode. Try this:

```
docker run -itd --cap-add=NET_ADMIN -d \
          --name=transmission \
          -v /mnt/extDrive1:/data \
          -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro \
          -e CREATE_TUN_DEVICE=true \
          -e OPENVPN_PROVIDER=EXPRESSVPN \
          -e OPENVPN_CONFIG=my_expressvpn_uk_-_london_udp \
          -e OPENVPN_USERNAME=XXX\
          -e OPENVPN_PASSWORD=XXX \
          -e WEBPROXY_ENABLED=false \
          -e LOCAL_NETWORK=192.168.0.0 \
          --log-driver json-file \
          --log-opt max-size=10m \
          -p 9091:9091 \
          haugene/transmission-openvpn
```

Comment: Genius!!! Worked perfectly! Thanks for your quick help